# Limiting User to one video

Tags: php, video, flowplayer

i'm developing a website with videos.
I need the user to watch only one video at a time. how can i achieve that?
can it be done by Sessions?
I'm using flowplayer as my video player

Comment: ı think yes, when someone visit your video you can start session and you cant let him watch another video until session destroy. but im not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions can be cleared by simply closing the browser or circumvented by opening another one (like FF and then chrome). You probably need to use a login system and decide how frequently they are allowed to watch videos

Comment: I've already created a login system. My idea was a session is created when the user logs in and when the users lands on the video player page, (for the first time) the player automatically starts a video and  $_SESSION['watchingvideo'] will be set to true, and will be false after the video finishes. So when watching a video, if the user opens a new video in a new tab, the session value is checked and the user is denied from watching the video.